# C/Obj-C noise generators always return 0 after the first run?

Tags: objective-c, c

Unfortunately the simplex/perlin noise generator I've always used is very bloated and java-based, and would be a pain to transfer to c/obj-c. I'm looking for better classes to use in an iOS version of a game, but i have an odd problem.

I have code that loops through each "tile" of a 2d background - it should calculate a noise value for each tile. In my java implementations it works fine.

However, each time I run the code, it appears to print a proper value the first time the breakpoint is hit, but from then on only ever returns zero:

```
for (double x = 0; x < 2; x++){
    for (double y = 0; y < 2; y++){
        double tileNoise = PerlinNoise2D(x,y,2,2,1);
    }
}
```

I've tried two different implementations, the current being this [c perlin library](http://paulbourke.net/libraries/perlin.c).

The breakpoint shows a value like `1.88858049852505e-308` the first time, but when I continue execution all subsequent breaks show "0".

What am I missing?

Comment: there is a `void init(void);` function

Comment: I added a call to that method but still nothing's changed. I'm coming from java so am trying to get used to the c/obj-c way of things.

Comment: It seems that dividing x by something, or incrementing it by .1 works - the numbers begin producing expected results

Comment: Try 2.0 instead of 2 in the method call.

Comment: @HotLicks, why should that make any difference?  It's going to get promoted as necessary anyway.

Comment: Well, you don't show what the Objective-C call looks like, but you could easily be passing an int in place of a double, depending on how it's all coded.  (Perhaps you should show us the real code.)

Comment: 1.88858049852505e-308, as close to 0 as you can get. :)

Answer (score 1):

Perlin noise is defined to be zero for integer locations. Try rotating, scaling or translating your space and see what happens example:

```
double u = 0.1;
double v = 0.1;
for (double x = 0; x < 2; x++){
    for (double y = 0; y < 2; y++){
        double tileNoise = PerlinNoise2D(x+u,y+v,2,2,1);
    }
}
```